# How to set permissions for a group automatically?

Tags: python, django

When creating the Django model, Django will automatically create permissions for CRUD operations. Provided that user groups have been created earlier, the question arises: how to add the necessary permissions for a group automatically?

At the moment, I create data migrations in which I add the necessary permissions for the group "manually". Maybe there is a way to do this without data migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Signal for that purpose in which you can assign permissions to the group.

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def assign_permission_signal_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       group = Group.objects.get(name='Group name')
       instance.groups.add(group)
       group.permissions.set('permission')
       instance.save()
```

Comment: It will be work only for User model and if instance created (new user added). But i say about when you create new model (as a class) and few permissions (for delete for example) on this model you need add to group (`app.remove_model`).

Comment: yes, the above solution will implement whenever you will save data then the signal will hit after saving data and assign permission to the group.

But at the time of creation, you need to write custom migration, whenever you will run migration you will add permissions to that group. Writing custom migration is the most appropriate way to handle such situations.